# Why does HTML mailto link open Brave browser?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm a web developer working on macOS "Big Sur".  I've noticed recently that if I create a web page in Visual Studio Code that contains an HTML anchor tag with a "mailto" href attribute and I launch a local web server using the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension, if I click that link, my Brave browser opens up.  What I would expect is that the Apple Mail application would open.

```
<body>
  <a href="mailto:smith@mac.com" id="email">smith@mac.com</a>
</body>
```

Is this a macOS problem or should I blame the Visual Studio Code extension?

Comment: Note that `mailto:` (like `http:`) indicates the URI component called _protocol_ or _scheme_. So your application (like VS Code) or OS may have a _protocol-handler_ pointing to an unexpected application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mailto:` links open in the system's default Email Reader. You might have this configured as Brave.

On macOS you change the default Email Reader from Preferences inside the Apple Mail app. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201607

In Chrome, there is also a setting to determine which website (e.g. Gmail) handles the protocol, I assume Brave works similarly: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308783?hl=en